# How can I set Empty pagestyle at the beginning of a part?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, parts

I am creating a document, that is separated in parts. What I would like to do, is have an empty `\pagestyle` at the beginning of the part.

My code is

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
 \pagestyle{empty}
 \part{First part}
 \chapter{First Chapter}
 \lipsum[1]
 \chapter{Second Chapter}
 \lipsum[2]
 \part{Second part}
 \chapter{Third Chapter}
 \lipsum[3]
 \chapter{Fourth Chapter}
 \lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

And my output is

[image]

How can I avoid having a page number at the first and second page(which is the white page after the part's title) of the part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the answer for the `book` document class, but with `memoir` it's a piece of cake:

```
\aliaspagestyle{part}{empty}
```

Consider that `memoir` was intended to replace `book`, `report` and `article`, offering more power to tweak it at the same time.

EDIT:
If you still wish to use the `book` class, put

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\part}{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \if@twocolumn
    \onecolumn
    \@tempswatrue
  \else
    \@tempswafalse
  \fi%
  \null\vfil%
  \secdef\@part\@spart%
}
\makeatother
```

in your preamble.

Comment: This indeed works with memoir, but I have a master thesis ready to be printed and I am not sure if I want to change the documentclass...

Comment: If you don't mess with `book`'s internals, you won't have big problems. Try to make a copy of your thesis, replace `book` with `memoir` and see what happens. I'll search a solution for the `book` class.

Comment: You need `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` as well.

Comment: Yeah I forgot them! Thanks! I'll edit the answer.

Comment: For the book class it's as easy as `\usepackage{etoolbox}` and `\patchcmd{\part}{plain}{empty}{}{}`

Comment: @egreg More or less thirty second after posting the answer I thought of the `etoolbox` package, but after I decided to leave the answer as is.